# canvas line angles strange render

Tags: javascript, canvas

Canvas very strangely draw angles in the example, left one is squarish and the right one is really sharp.:

[image]

```
    guideCtx.lineWidth = screenWidth*.003;

    var xC = x0 = e.clientX;
    var yC = y0 = e.clientY;

    var r = r0 = 160;


    guideCtx.beginPath();
    guideCtx.lineCap = 'square';

    //guideCtx.arc(xC, yC, r, -Math.PI*2/3, -Math.PI/2.99, false);

    xC = x0;
    yC = y0 - r0/Math.sin(Math.PI/6);
    r = r0/Math.tan(Math.PI/6);

    guideCtx.arc(xC, yC, r, Math.PI*4/6, Math.PI*2/6, true);

    guideCtx.lineTo(x0, y0 + r0);
    guideCtx.lineTo(x0 - r0*Math.sin(Math.PI/3), y0 - r0*Math.sin(Math.PI/6));

    guideCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
    guideCtx.stroke();

    guideCtx.closePath();
```

Anybody knows how to make those the same, without closing and opening the path?

Comment: Using round end caps and joins will make line ends and angles look the same, but closing the path before stroking will make it look much better.  If you don't close the path, the render engine will have no way of knowing that the two lines are supposed to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `lineCap` (or `lineJoin`) to for example `round`.

Or you can adjust the miter value and use miter line-join and limit:

```
ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
ctx.miterLimit = 5;     /// this will adjust the spike
```

Also, your `var` usage does not do what you think it do:

```
var xC = x0 = e.clientX;
```

This will allocate `xC`, `x0` however will end up on window object. You need to explicitly define them:

```
var xC, x0;
xC = x0 = e.clientX;
```

Comment: @NikTerentyev please provide a fiddle